# IPFS connection : ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5001)

Tags: python, ipfs

i'm trying to connect my python program to IPFS api to mint some nft.
I started the IPFS daemon on the " /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001 " but when i try to connect the client i get this error :

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5001): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v0/version?stream-channels=true (Caused by NewConnectionError('<ipfshttpclient.requests_wrapper.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fac0ddf97c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

this is my code :

```
import ipfshttpclient



client = ipfshttpclient.connect()
print(client.version())
```

it fails on connect() function, i miss something ? what i can do for can start the connection?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you ensure the webserver is running on the specified port? E.g. `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

Comment: node      168     1000   18u  IPv4  21879      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:35535 (LISTEN)
python3.9 912     1000    4u  IPv4  23500      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:36585 (LISTEN)
python3.9 912     1000    8u  IPv4  25774      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:39753 (LISTEN)

Comment: this is what i get. But on power shall ipfs daemon says : Initializing daemon...
go-ipfs version: 0.11.0
Repo version: 11
API server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/5001
WebUI: http://127.0.0.1:5001/webui
Gateway (readonly) server listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/8080
Daemon is ready